# Set primary key for range query in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, primary-key

I want to create a table with these columns: `id1, id2, type, time, data, version`.

The frequent query is:

1. `select * from table_name where id1 = ... and id2 =... and type = ...`
2. `select * from table_name where id1=  ... and type = ... and time > ... and time < ...`

I don't know how to set the primary key for the fast query?

Comment: in the first query you mean `where id1 = ... and id2 =...`?

Comment: yes, it should be ```select * from table_name where id1 = ... and id2 =... and type = ...```

Answer (score 2):

As you have two different queries, you will likely need to have two different tables for them to perform well.  This is not unusual for Cassandra data models.  Keep in mind that for both of these, the PRIMARY KEY definition in Cassandra is largely dependent on the cardinalities and anticipated query patterns.  As you have only provided the latter, you may need to make adjustments based on the cardinalities of `id1`, `id2`, and `type`.

`select * from table_name where id1 = X and id2 = Y and type = Z;`

So here I'm going to make an educated guess that `id1` and `id2` are nigh unique (high cardinality), as IDs usually are.  I don't know how many types are available in your application, but as long as there aren't more than 10,000 this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name_by_ids (
    id1 TEXT,
    id2 TEXT,
    type TEXT,
    time TIMESTAMP,
    data TEXT,
    version TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ((id1,id2),type));
```

This will key your partitions on a joint hash of `id1` and `id2`, sorting the rows inside by `type` (default ascending).

`select * from table_name where id1= X and type = Z and time > A and time < B;`

Likewise, the table to support this query will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name_by_id1_time (
    id1 TEXT,
    id2 TEXT,
    type TEXT,
    time TIMESTAMP,
    data TEXT,
    version TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ((id1),type,time))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (type ASC, time DESC);
```

Again, this should work as long as you don't have more than several thousand type/time combinations.

One final adjustment that I would make though, would be around judging just how many type/time combinations you expect to have over the life of the application.  If this data will grow over time, then the above will cause the partitions to grow to an unmaintainable point.  To keep that from happening, I'd also recommend adding a time "bucket."

```
version TEXT,
month_bucket TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ((id1,month_bucket),type,time))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (type ASC, time DESC);
```

Likewise for this, the query will need to be adjusted as well:

```
select * from table_name_by_id1_time
where id1= 'X' and type = 'Z'
and month_bucket='201910'
and time > '2019-10-07 00:00:00' and time < '2019-10-07 16:22:12';
```

Hope this helps.

> how do I guarantee the atomicity of these two insertions?

Simply put, you can run the two `INSERT`s together in an atomic batch.

```
BEGIN BATCH

  INSERT INTO table_name_by_ids (
    id1, id2, type, time, data, version
  ) VALUES (
    'X', 'Y', 'Z', '2019-10-07 12:00:01','stuff','1.0'
  ) ;

  INSERT INTO table_name_by_id1_time (
    id1, id2, type, time, data, version, month_bucket
  ) VALUES (
    'X', 'Y', 'Z', '2019-10-07 12:00:01','stuff','1.0','201910'
  );

APPLY BATCH;
```

For more info, check out the DataStax docs on atomic batches: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html

Comment: Thank you so much. If I have two tables, that means I need to insert a record to two different tables when I want to add a record in this database. So how do I guarantee the atomicity of these two insertions? If the system crash after I insert a record to the first table,   the data in these two table may not be consistent.

Comment: @HaoChen Edit made.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply

Comment: I found that the range query is very slow, ```select * from table_name where id1= X and type = Z and time > A and time < B```. ```time``` is the timestamp, so we have too many type/time combinations, more than several thousand.  Is there any more efficient way for the query?